# Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$TreeNodeException: execute, tree:

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, pyspark, parquet, google-cloud-dataproc

When trying to save a PySpark DataFrame into a parquet in GCS, I ran into the error below:

`Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$TreeNodeException: Binding attribute, tree: col_1#5671`

However, I printed the schema before saving it as a parquet, and the schema does have `col_1`

Comment: What is the query did you make before saving the dataframe?

Comment: In addition to sharing the full query (not only the write) you executed, can you also share the full stack trace of the error you're getting?